# Прекращение звонка после 32 секунд

Tags: linux, asterisk, sip, voip, телефония

АТС - AskoziaPBX

```
SIP trunk:
type=friend
insecure=port,invite
canreinvite=no
context=from-siptrunk
```

Регистрация на сервере провайдера не требуется.

Звонок прерывается через 32 секунды.

Comment: `asterisk -rvvvv` во время разрыва